# How to use Wordpress Text Editor in a custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How can we use default wordpress text editor for my wordpress plugin.Any suggections please?

Comment: Check out following article it's help you. [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96692/adding-rich-text-editor-to-my-plugine](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96692/adding-rich-text-editor-to-my-plugin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The WordPress Text editor is an application of the [TinyMCE Editor](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).  You can utilize the files located in wp_includes/js/tinymce and create an instance of the editor on your own, according to [the documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/documentation.php).

Check out this article for example instructions:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-i-can-use-tinymce-for-my-own-plugin

Answer (score 6):

As of Wordpress 3.3 `the_editor` has deprecated in favor of `wp_editor`. wp_editor uses the new media uploader and takes advantage of all the new features of Wordpress 3.5.x Documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

A very good example of how to use it can be found at Wptuts+ here: http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/tips-articles/quick-tip-using-wp_editor/

Answer (score 2):

very easy try this code 
it's working

```
 wp_editor( $distribution, 'distribution', array( 'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, ul, pH, pH_min', "media_buttons" => true, "textarea_rows" => 8, "tabindex" => 4 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy:

```
<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id ); ?>
```

This will generate a lot of html tags.  But the one you will be interested in is the textarea with its name set to $editor_id.  So when the form is submitted, you can save that content.

You can find more info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor