# Using wordpress editor in my projects

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg

I think CKEditor is the most powerful WYSIWYG Editor, but CKEditor have some problem, and I found the Wordpress editor is powerful than CKEditor :)

But I don't know what is wordpress editor ? Is it OpenSource ?

How can I use WordPress Editor in my projects?

**UPDATE:**

I mean was wordpress default editor :

[image]

Comment: https://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: are you talking about this https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor/ ?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan thanks, wordpress theme is beautiful and have more different plugins to TinyMCE, I need exactly this editor because I cannot customize TineMCE :(

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj No, I mean was default wordpress editor

Comment: ok, so where would you like to use this WordPress editor? I mean in which coding project you want to use it?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj I have developed a CMS with Laravel (PHP), I want use Wordpress Editor in my CMS

Comment: OK but its inbuilt with WordPress  and WordPress is open source

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj Thanks, I know this, I want to know is there any package or library have this editor as a separate project ?

Answer (score 2):

Below answers guide you properly I hope

[How to use Wordpress Text Editor in a custom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141288/how-to-use-wordpress-text-editor-in-a-custom-plugin)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/daily-tip-how-to-set-the-default-editor-to-visual-or-html-in-wordpress/

https://www.bloggersignal.com/set-html-editor-as-default-editor-in-wordpress/

https://www.webhostinghero.com/how-to-switch-the-wordpress-editor-to-html-by-default/

Answer (score 0):

You need just add the following filter in your function file ,
Just copy below code and past in your child-theme function file and that completing hard refresh

```
 add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false', 10);
```